# How to change autocomplete font size on Komodo Edit 7?

Tags: autocomplete, komodoedit

I've recently upgraded to Komodo Edit 7 from 6.1, and while the upgrade has been rather smooth, the font size for the autocomplete suggestion's font size suddenly became huge

[image]

Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on Komodo Edit forums: http://community.activestate.com/node/7289

To fix this, you need to create (if you haven't done so already) a [`userChrome.css`](http://community.activestate.com/faq/customizing-komodo-ui) file in the `<application data folder>/XRE/chrome` ([app data location for different operating systems](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-file-locations#appdata_dir)) folder to override the original styling of the autocomplete menu. Copy the code below into the file and save, then restart Komodo and the menu font size should return to normal.

```
scintilla > panel[anonid="autocompletepopup"] .ko-autocomplete-item {
    font-size: 100% !important;
}
```